# Simple question about using determinant to find eigenvalues of $\hat{S_x} + \hat{S_y}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

The problem is:

Find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the operator
$\hat{S_x} + \hat{S_y}$ where $\hat{S_i}$ is the spin
operator in the i direction  (i = x,y,z).

The first step of their solution is to compute the
determinant of  $\hbar/2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1-i \\ 1+i & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$

det {$\hbar/2 \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda & 1-i \\ 1+i & -\lambda \end{pmatrix}$} = 0

gives

$(\hbar/2)^4 [\lambda^2-(1-i)(1+i)] = 0$

which gives

$\lambda=\pm \sqrt 2$

But then they say thus, the eigenvalues are $\pm \hbar / \sqrt 2$.  Why
aren't the eigenvalues just $\pm \sqrt 2$?

Comment: Your matrix is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix is wrong. It should be

det {$\begin{pmatrix} -\lambda & \hbar/2 (1-i) \\ \hbar/2 (1+i) & -\lambda \end{pmatrix}$} = 0

Now when you compute the determinant, it should be okay.